# How to prevent more then one object's init call?

Tags: javascript

Our plugin function is something like: `var pluginName = function(selector, settings){}`. So user call it like `var myPlugin = new pluginName('#id', {settings})`. But how to detect that user called it again, for example, with new options: `myPlugin = new pluginName('#id', {settings_2})`?

We need to detect this to prevent double events attaching: something like destroy created object/remove events and call init again.

So problem is we dont have access to `myPlugin` variable to check it.

Comment: Search for "how to implement singleton in JavaScript".

Answer (score 1):

Just put the plugin around it's own scope:

```
var pluginName = (function(){
    var plugin_created = false; 
    var plugin = function(selector, settings){
        if(plugin_created) return false;
        plugin_created = true;
        //rest of the plugin class
    }
    return plugin;
})();
```

So when you create it for the first time it will set it's local scope variable to `true` and then any other creations will fail.